# JavaFX. Как сделать модальное окно для получения папки удаленного ПК

Tags: java, javafx

Как в *JavaFX* реализовать модальное окно для получения папки удаленного компьютера?
Для получения папки на самом компьютере делал через *DirectoryChooser*. Может есть аналогичное окно? В документации ни чего не нашел(наверно плохо искал).

Comment: К удаленному компьютеру можно подключаться и получать файлы совершенно разными способами. Стандартный DialogChooser может работать с подключенными сетевыми дисками, а так есть всякие FTP, SSH, UNC, HTTP и т.д. Сначала определитесь с механизмом, который будете использовать и который доступен на удаленном компьютере.

Comment: @AlexKrass Благодарю за объяснение. Я предполагал что штатными средствами JavaFX это не решить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все что связанно с подключением к компьютерам и ФС в Java/JavaFX используются библиотеки которые устанавливают соединение. Для понимания, какую библиотеку применять необходимо знать, какое подключение поддерживает удаленный компьютер. Поэтому в JavaFX можно создать окно "выбор подключения" и создать реализацию для каждого подключения которое требуется.